# New Year Maths $2019$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics

$$\;\;\;\color{red}{\binom {20}{19}}\\
\color{orange}{+\binom {19}{a}
+{\binom  ab}}\\
\color{green}{+\binom bc
+\binom cd}\\
\color{blue}{+\binom de+
\binom ef}\\
\color{purple}{+\binom fg+\binom gh}\\
\color{magenta}{+\binom hk}\\[15pt]
\color{orange}=\\[10pt]
\color{red}{2019}\\[15pt]
\color{orange}{a,b,}
\color{green}{c,d,}
\color{blue}{e,f,}
\color{purple}{g,h,}
\color{magenta}k\color{orange}{=?}\\[20pt]$$
$$\color{red}{\text{Happy New Year!}}$$

---

*Note* - Please feel free to post any other interesting identities based on the same theme!

Comment: i think you're missing the g,h term. Else it is a bit too easy

Comment: You're right... thanks! It's there now.

Comment: I was missing you ! **Happy New Year !**

Comment: Haha thanks @ClaudeLeibovici - Happy New Year!

Comment: Are they all natural numbers? And is $19\geq a\geq b\geq c \geq\cdots\geq k$?

Comment: @alex.jordan Ideally yes. But I look forward to being surprised!

Comment: Is python allowed, or is that cheating? :P

Comment: @Anvit Anything goes! Or, shall we say, a computational approach is acceptable :).

Comment: Just curious, why did you skip $i$ and $j$ ?

Comment: $i$ and $j$ are often unused to avoid confusing one for the other. They are also commonly used as loop variables in programming...

Comment: @Anvit - Good question! $i, j$ are usually used for indexing, and probably for the same reason, elements in the standard $3\times 3$ matrix are often labelled $\left[\begin{array}&a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&k\end{array}\right]$.

Comment: Is $9$ the least numbers of unknowns , in order to solve it?  Assuming that you start again with $\binom{20}{19}$ .

Comment: Tell us your thoughts on the problem. What have you tried? Show your work. And lose the colors.

Comment: There are $19$ up-votes.... Should I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple python script yielded the following results for `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,k` such that $19>a> b> c> \cdots > k\geq 0$

`16,14,12,7,6,5,3,1,0
16,14,12,7,6,5,3,2,0
17,14,10,7,6,5,3,1,0
17,14,10,7,6,5,3,2,0
18,15,14,10,9,5,4,2,0
18,15,14,10,9,5,4,3,1
18,15,14,10,9,5,4,3,2
18,17,16,12,10,9,7,6,1
18,17,16,12,10,9,7,6,5
18,17,16,12,11,9,7,2,0
18,17,16,12,11,9,7,5,0
18,17,16,12,11,9,7,6,2
18,17,16,12,11,9,7,6,4
18,17,16,12,11,10,8,3,0
18,17,16,12,11,10,8,5,0`

Comment: Nice and complete solution! (+1)

Answer (score 32):

$$\color{red}{\binom {20}{19}}
+\color{orange}{\binom {19}{16}
+{\binom  {16}{14}}}+ 
\color{green}{\binom {14}{12}
+\binom {12}{7}}+
\color{blue}{\binom {7}{6}+
\binom {6}{5}}+
\color{purple}{\binom {5}{3}+\binom {3}{1}}+
\color{magenta}{\binom {1}{0}}
=\color{red}{2019}$$

[image]

Comment: Nice! We can make each of JMoravitz's solutions into a tree and and then vote which tree is the most beautiful ...

Comment: Very nice animation! (+1)

Answer (score 14):

$$\color{red}{\binom{20}{19}}+\color{orange}{\binom{19}{18}}+\color{orange}{\binom{18}{17}}+\color{green}{\binom{17}{16}}+\color{green}{\binom{16}{12}}+\color{blue}{\binom{12}{11}}+\color{blue}{\binom{11}{10}}+\color{purple}{\binom{10}{8}}+\color{purple}{\binom{8}{5}}+\color{magenta}{\binom{5}{0}}\color{orange}=\color{red}{2019}$$
$\color{red}{\text{Happy New Year!}}$

Comment: Nice! Hope you don't mind some colors :D

Comment: Thank you,  Zacky!

Answer (score 10):

$$\begin{align}&{7\choose H}+\color{red}{9\choose A}+\color{blue}{11\choose P}+{\color{blue}{12\choose P}}+\color{green}{13\choose Y}+\\
&{8\choose N}+\color{magenta}{16\choose E}+{15\choose W}+\\
&\color{green}{14\choose Y}+\color{magenta}{17\choose E}+\color{red}{10\choose A}+\binom{18}{R}=
2019.\end{align}$$

> $\binom76+\binom85+\binom98+\binom{10}8+\binom{11}{10}+\binom{12}{10}+\binom{13}{12}+\binom{14}{12}+\binom{15}{13}+\binom{16}{14}+\binom{17}{14}+\binom{18}{15}=2019.$

Comment: Cool!  ... too bad that the same letters don't go with the same numbers on top ... did you try that?

Comment: Nope, first I tried $\binom7{H}+\binom8{A}+\cdots+\binom{18}{R}$, but then had to adjust (by trial and error, no coding).

Answer (score 2):

$\color{red}{{20 \choose 19}+{19\choose 16}}+\color{orange}{{16\choose 3}+{3\choose 1}}+\color{green}{{1\choose 2}+{2\choose 2}}+\color{blue}{{2\choose 466}+{466\choose 465}}+\color{purple}{{465\choose 466}+{466\choose 467}}=\color{magenta}{2019}$.