# A problem on norm

Tags: functional-analysis

I found the following proof in the book:

For $1\leq p<q<\infty$, let $x\in l^p$ such that $||x||_q\leq 1$, then we have $|x(j)|^q\leq |x(j)|^p$ for all $j\in\Bbb N$. This shows that $||x||_p\leq 1$ For nonzero $x$, consider $\frac{x}{||x||_p}$, then we have $||x||_q\leq ||x||_r$.
Thus, we have $l^q\subset l^p$.

My questions are as follows

- Why is $l^p$ is a proper subspace of $l^q$ instead of just subspace?
- Does the inequality hold for $0<p<q<\infty$?

Comment: What is $n$ in  $1 \leq j \leq n$? In finite dimensions all $\ell^{p}$'s are the same.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Please see my recent edits.

Comment: $\ell^{q}$ is a proper subspace of $\ell^{p}$ whenver $0 <p<q<\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Does the same proof work? Why is the proper subset  there?

Comment: Take $x(j) = j^{-1/p}$. Then $x\in \ell^q\setminus\ell^p$.

Comment: @Gribouillis Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: @JohnNash Seen (I think you directed me here from the Happy new year post), let me take a look, thanks.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon yes, thank you for coming here.